# Problems with SPARQL Tutorial - A First SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, jena

I'm a starter to the sparql, following the sparql tutorial from https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_query1.html

I used the sparql query function like this:

```
caihanzhi@ererererermaodeMacBook-Air bin % sparql --data=/Users/caihanzhi/Desktop/vc-db-1.rdf --query=/Users/caihanzhi/Desktop/q1.rq
```

and the `vc-db-1.rdf` is

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'
  xmlns:vCard='http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#'
   >

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/JohnSmith">
    <vCard:FN>John Smith</vCard:FN>
    <vCard:N rdf:parseType="Resource">
    <vCard:Family>Smith</vCard:Family>
    <vCard:Given>John</vCard:Given>
    </vCard:N>
  </rdf:Description>

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/RebeccaSmith">
    <vCard:FN>Becky Smith</vCard:FN>
    <vCard:N rdf:parseType="Resource">
    <vCard:Family>Smith</vCard:Family>
    <vCard:Given>Rebecca</vCard:Given>
    </vCard:N>
  </rdf:Description>

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/SarahJones">
    <vCard:FN>Sarah Jones</vCard:FN>
    <vCard:N rdf:parseType="Resource">
    <vCard:Family>Jones</vCard:Family>
    <vCard:Given>Sarah</vCard:Given>
    </vCard:N>
  </rdf:Description>

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/MattJones">
    <vCard:FN>Matt Jones</vCard:FN>
    <vCard:N
    vCard:Family="Jones"
    vCard:Given="Matthew"/>
  </rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

And the `q1.rq` is

```
SELECT ?x
WHERE { ?x  <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#FN>  "John Smith" }
```

But it failed to query. Bash told me that:

```
Encountered " "{" "{ "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "\ufeff" ...
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "describe" ...
    "construct" ...
    "ask" ...
```

if anyone knows how to solve it please do not hesitate to provide help!

Comment: The files are all written by the text editor.

Comment: then use a different text editor or try to write everything into a single line. I can't reproduce this but obviously the first line never makes it to the parser. Please double check your file and your encoding. Maybe you can also share the file that fails?

Comment: You can also do `cat -v /Users/caihanzhi/Desktop/q1.rq` to show the file including non-printing characters

Comment: That may work! When I typed `cat -v .....`It showed other things more than what I wrote. I'm trying to use another text editor. Thanks a lot!!